# Why KeyCodeNumber exception after signing Blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, signing

We've signed a 4.7 Blackberry application with the 4.6 code-signing tool. But when starting the application a second time it throws a 'KeyCodeNumber exception'.

Anybody some clues to why we get this exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyCodeNumber exceptions have todo with the verification process.

Blackberry [published an article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/832062/Support_-_Preventing_verification_errors.html?nodeid=1499031&vernum=0) describing how to prevent verification errors:

> When developing Java applications for
>   the BlackBerry smartphone, you may
>   encounter any of the following
>   verification errors or errors similar
>   to the following:
>
> Verification Error 3141 Module
>   'MyMIDlet' has verification error
>   (<###>) at offset <###>. Error
>   starting MyMIDlet: Module 'MyMIDlet'
>   has verification error (<####>) at
>   offset <###>." These errors often
>   occur when creating MIDlets. They are
>   inherently hard to debug because the
>   same error message can apply to a
>   number of problems.

The following is a list of possible solutions to prevent or correct verification errors:

1. If you started by building a Java
   Archive (JAR) file and then used the
   RIM Application Program Compiler
   (RAPC) to create .cod files, make
   sure you turn obfuscation off when
   building the JAR file. The RAPC
   compiler performs its own
   obfuscation and issues may occur if
   the code is already obfuscated.
2. Remove any System.out.* calls. These
   generally do nothing on the
   BlackBerry smartphone, but they
   might cause verification errors.
3. Remove unused import statements.
4. Explicitly specify the access for
   each function or variable. For
   example, make sure each one is
   specified as public, private, or
   protected.
5. If you are working with a MIDlet,
   make sure the MIDlet class is
   declared as public.
6. Verification errors may occur if the
   COD file is corrupted or if it was
   not signed correctly. Make sure that
   you perform a clean rebuild and that
   you re-sign your application.
   Reinstall the application on the
   BlackBerry smartphone.
7. Comment out any non-executable code.
   Verification errors might be related
   to the size of the main code file
   and the library files. If you
   comment out non-executable code, the
   file sizes change, which may correct
   the problem.
8. If you have created any classes that
   inherit from RIM classes, change the
   name of any custom methods and
   members that you created in those
   classes. This makes sure that you
   have not named any methods or
   members of the same name in the
   internal RIM classes.
9. If your application is using
   BlackBerry® Device Software 3.8 or
   later, verification errors occur
   when an application that implements
   the
   javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore
   class is compiled using BlackBerry®
   Java® Development Environment
   (BlackBerry JDE) earlier than
   version 4.0. This occurs if the
   application uses either the
   addRecordListener or
   removeRecordListener methods of the
   RecordStore class. To resolve this
   issue, recompile the application
   using BlackBerry JDE 4.0 or later.
10. There is a problem with how the
     BlackBerry® Java® Virtual Machine
     (BlackBerry JVM) handles the
     referencing of a class directly
     within the constructor of another
     class. The following is an example:
     Class1 class1= new
     Class1(Class2.class.getName());

To work around this issue, do not make the class call within a constructor as shown in the following example:

```
Class1 class1;
String className = Class2.class.getName();
Class1 = new Class1(className);
```

Remove references to a static instance variable from an inner class. For example, the following code example could cause an error:

```
public class MyOuterClass {
    static int var;
    class MyInnerClass {
        public void doSomething() {
            var = 7;
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few ways you can remove these references, such as creating get/set methods for var in the outer class or modifying the logic to pull MyInnerClass out of MyOuterClass.

1. The build procedure normally
   compiles from the java source file
   with the javac command, and then
   runs preverify.exe file and then
   RAPC. Add the following command line
   arguments to javac to help avoid
   issues in earlier versions of the
   RAPC:

   javac.exe -source 1.3 -target 1.1
2. Some methods that are very long can
   cause verification errors. By
   breaking these methods into helper
   methods, you can reduce the
   likelihood of verification errors.
3. Although not as likely, some very
   long method definitions (with 10 or
   more parameters), and some very long
   constant definitions (long package
   structure and/or long names) can
   also cause verification errors.

Comment: Great post but this is why mobile dev is INSANE ;)